# Spring Boot - cannot read properties if running in AWS ECS

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ecs, spring-profiles

We currently have a Spring boot web service thats working fine. Like any normal spring boot app, it has an application.properties file where it retrieves certain parameters. Now, we have migrated it to run in AWS ECS. We have migrated all parameters defined in the properties file to the environment params in the ECS Task Definition (json file).

The issue is it can't read the parameters in the environment params of the task. Even if the properties file is still there, it still can't read anything. We have read the documentation and it said that this would all be automatic, but we can't retrieve anything.

Below is the task definition file:

```
{
  "family": "my-svc-test",
  "taskRoleArn": "<our task role>",
  "executionRoleArn": "<our execution role>",
  "cpu": "512",
  "memory": "1024",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "my-svc-test",
      "cpu": 0,
      "image": "<our image>",
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 20080,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 20080
        }
      ],
      "command": [
        "java",
        "-jar",
        "app.jar"
      ],
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "PARAM.NAME",
          "value": "paramvalue"
        },
        {
          "name": "PARAM.NAME2",
          "value": "paramvalue2"
        }
      ],
      "secrets": [
        {
          "name": "DB.USERNAME",
          "valueFrom": "<db password in ssm>"
        }
      ],
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/mysvc",
          "awslogs-region": "ap-southeast-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "volumes": [],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "networkMode": "awsvpc"
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details. In my experience this does work as expected, so you must be missing something. Please provide your ECS task definition details, like the `environment {}` section.

Comment: @MarkB Edited my post to include the ECS Task definition file.

Comment: It's probably a wording/naming problem with your environment variables. We need to see the actual environment variable name, and the same property name in application.properties. You've obfuscated that in your answer. How about locally, if you set the property as an environment variable, does Spring pick it up locally?

Comment: @MarkB i tried downloading the docker image from AWS ECR and in my local machine, did a docker run supplying all the env variables, it worked. It just won't work when in ECS